# How to do variable interpolation in a windows batch file using the Qt "system" command?

Tags: windows, qt, batch-file

When developing an application with Qt the project file has the file extension "pro". In this pro file one can perform platform-dependent commands by using the "system" directive. Example:

```
RESPONSE = $$system( cmd /c dir)
```

I want to use variable interpolation. Windows uses for this the % character. When I create a batch file, called utc.bat that writes its output to the file utc.txt, having as content:

```
@echo off
REM for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
echo %Year%-
```

and run it from a terminal the content of utc.txt is:

```
2017-
```

If I run the same command from within the pro file:

```
system(utc.bat > utc.txt)
```

the content of utc.txt is

```
-
```

Apparently the variable interpolation %Year% does not work. I hope somebody knows the answer of how to get it working.

Comment: Uh, the line in the batch file that sets `Year` is commented out.

Comment: This might help? https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake OR $$_DATE_ I cannot remember exact format for interpolation.

Comment: the _DATE macro gives the *local* time

Comment: with REM the FOR loop is still be carried out (on my Windows 10 machine) but with much less output

Comment: That's not possible.  Check again, in a new command window.

Comment: Write a simple command line utility that posts UTC time in the format you like to the console and then use it from QMake while redirecting its output like you do?